# Flipping a coin using RandomGenerator

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that simulates flipping a coin. The first time the coin flips heads I want the program to exit. The first statement in my while loop flips the coin once. Then i have a if statement that says if the coin that I just flipped was heads exit the program. But my program is not working the way i want. Sometimes

My question is am I flipping the coin once or twice per 1 cycle in the while loop? Does the coin get flipped once in the while loop and then a second time in the if condition? I've tested it but it gives me a different result with different errors every time and I can't figure out why.

Is the if condition correct for what I'm trying to do in my program?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class CoinToss extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run(){


     while (true){
        println(flipCoin());
        if (flipCoin() == "heads"){
               break;
             }   
        }
  }

public String flipCoin(){
   String flip = rgen.nextBoolean() ? "heads" : "tails"; 
   return flip;
 }


public RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: You run flipCoin() twice in while loop.

Comment: Note as well that you're comparing strings with ==, use .equals() instead.

Comment: For my personal culture, am I the only one to dislike the use of `break` statements when it can be avoided ?

Comment: @Bartdude Is there a more elegant way of exiting the program instead of break?

Comment: @Jessica Use the condition that results in a `break`, as part of the conditions in the `while` loop. @Bartdude Yes, `break` and `continue` are just fancy versions of `goto`.

Comment: @Jessica : as Rajesh advises ... I find the answer from Marco here under is the best of all answers.

Comment: @berry120 Actually, in this particular case, since he only uses compile-time constant strings, using `==` should actually return his desired result.  (I agree he still shouldn't use `==` though, because its bad for maintainability.)

Comment: @AJMansfield Sure, I was very careful to avoid phrasing it as though I meant that - the point being the use of `==` is, academic purposes aside, pretty much always a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you call `flipCoin()` the method runs, so it runs once on the line `println(flipCoin());` and once on `if (flipCoin() == "heads")`. The results of the two calls may not be the same, you should store the result and then use the result, so:

```
    while (true){
        String result=flipCoin();
        System.out.println(result);
        if (result.equals("heads")){
            break;
        }   
    }
```

Note also that using == with strings will (under most circumstances) always give false; this is because `==` asks if they are literally the same object, not if their contents are equal (two pieces of paper can both have "hi" written on them but they are not the same piece of paper). `.equals` compares the **contents** of the two strings (i.e. if they say the same word(s)).

I have kept my modifications as close to your code as possible but you may want to consider the following possible improvements:

- `break;` can have legitimate usages but usually is unnecessary, you could avoid it by:

  ```
  String result=flipCoin();
  while (result.equals("heads")==false){
      System.out.println(result);
      result=flipCoin();

  }
  ```
- using strings as identifiers again has its place, but consider all the different capitalisations you could use (heads, Heads, HEADS), an enum may be a better choice.

Comment: @RichardTingle Thanks! I can't believe I made that mistake. There is even a section in my book that says don't get .equals and == concepts confused with each other.

Comment: One of the reasons for this (common) error is that your method flipCoin() not only flips the coin, but also fetches the state of the coin. Ideally, the operation that gets the state should stand apart from the operation that changes the state of the coin. The lack of separation between both operations makes it easy to make mistakes like this.

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani I'm enclined to agree, presumably a Coin class that has seperate .flip() and .getSide() methods. Of course thats quite a lot of overhead, possibly worth it though

Comment: @RichardTingle in my experience for most small examples like this object oriented design usually comes with more overhead compared to the straight approach as this one. But in most cases it's worth it as the example grows. oh and is there a special reason to compare the result of a boolean method to false?

Comment: @MarcoForberg Totally agree with you. No special reason, I have a tendancy to keep my answer code as close to the question code as possible but as this was part of the "ideas to consider" section anyway that was perhaps an oversight. I have changed it in any case

Comment: @JessicaM. I've changed my second block of code such that it prints out each coin flip, including the final heads that leads to the program ending as I think that is closer to your intention. My previous code would print out nothing if the first coin flip was heads

Comment: @MarcoForberg If heads and tails were represented by enums (say HEADS and TAILS), then for clarity you'd want to return the enum instead of a boolean, and compare the returned value to a specific side. With a `boolean` the comparison is necessary, but adding Enums with specific comparisons makes it harder to make a mistake.

Comment: That was supposed to be "With a `boolean` the comparison is **un** necessary but I guess you got that.

Comment: @RichardTingle Sorry to ask but can you re upload the code back to how you wrote it before? You suggested exiting the while loop without using break and doing something like ....if (result.equals == "heads")... or something along those lines.

Comment: @JessicaM. No problem at all, have reverted it, note the behaviour that as it stands it doesnt print the final head that terminates the program. Note also that on stack overflow you can always look at all the old versions from the edited link

Comment: P.s. I would like to say that my 8 minute response time was a coincidence and im not always on stack overflow. I'd like to say that but it would be a lie

Comment: @RichardTingle Lol. 8 minutes is pretty quick. I was not expecting you to read my message until later tonight.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is wrong.  Your code is currently flipping a coin, printing the value, then flipping another coin to test the exit.  The problem being that if you flip two coils in a row, you do not necessarily always get the same result.

A much better way to do it:

```
for(;;)
    if(rgen.nextBoolean()) {
        println("heads");
        break;
    } else
        println("tails");
```

You do NOT need a seperate method for actually flipping the coin, because the method already exists, called `rgen.nextBoolean()`.  And having the method return a string, and *then* processing the string, is very inefficient.  While efficency doesn't matter for this, don't get into bad habits doing stuff like that, or it may bite you later.

EDIT: In response to some of the comments, here is a more universal, object-oriented way to do this:

```
public enum CoinFlipResult {
    HEADS, TAILS;
    @Override
    public String toString(){ 
        switch(this){
        case HEADS: return "heads"; break;
        case TAILS: return "tails"; break;
        }
    } //could have just done `name().toLowerCase()`, but I like this better
}

public CoinFlipResult flipCoin(){
    if(rgen.nextBoolean())
        return CoinFlipResult.HEADS;
    else
        return CoinFlipResult.TAILS;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    CoinFlipResult flip;
    do {
        flip = flipCoin();
        println(flip);
    } while(flip != CoinFlipResult.HEADS)
}
```

Comment: @AJMansfield Why the empty for loop, as this is efectively a while(true)? Also, you have made the multiline-braceless-??? into an art form, managing to get 5 lines into the for loop without braces. I'm impressed but I'm not sure this is a good thing for readability: http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/

Comment: Regarding the "method return a string, and then processing the string" i agree that its slower, but not nessissarily a bad thing, you have effectively implied that true==heads without ever really stating it explicitly, this assumption could polute a larger program until you start having to have conversion points where in one part of the program true==heads and annother where true==tails. Even if those parts never meet it still is harder to read. Of course the string comparison is bad and could be avoided, but I think there are better ways of avoiding it

Comment: @RichardTingle I added a better version.

Comment: @RichardTingle IDK, I just like it better.

Comment: @AJMansfield Can't argue with that, we all have different coding styles. +1 for the enum example

Comment: also nice +1 for enum approach

Answer (score 3):

Me dislikes unneccessary `break`s and **DO NOT compare String with ==**:

```
String result = null;
do {
    result = flipCoin()
    println(result);
} while (!"tails".equals(result));
```

and i suggest introducing String constants for "heads" and "tails"

Comment: @MarcoForberg Once I read one of the answers I immediately realized my mistake. I can't believe I got == and .equals mixed up. Thanks for your help.